# Can my virtual machine connect to the host's network?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I have the VirtualBox installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 (this is what I call the "host machine") and, into this VirtualBox, I have a Xubuntu based distro named Honeydrive (this is what I call the "guess").

I would like to connect the guess at the same network the host is connected.

For example, when I turn on my notebook, it connects to my internal network and gains an IP adress (usually: 192.168.0.13). The host usually gains the IP 192.168.0.15.

But the guess always have a IP 10.0.2.15, in a network that only exists into VirtualBox, what forces me to redirect external connections to the host and then redirect from the host to the guess...

Is there some way to make guess act like that to? (simply to connect to my internal network and get some IP from my router, as my physical machines...)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the connection type to bridged.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for aswering!  I'll test it and come back to tell you what happened.

Comment: It was quite simple!  And I readed the VirtualBox's manual and I didn't understand this     :|